# Batch renaming in certain criteria

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, renaming

After much searching I'm not entirely sure how to move further with this so I was wondering if anyone could help out? I'm writing a batch renamer that looks at files that will look like this:

```
Name_Project_Date_CharacterName.wav
Name_Project_Date_CharacterName_Declicked.wav
Name_Project_Project2_Date_CharacterName.wav
Name_Project_Project2_Date_CharacterName_Declicked.wav
```

I need to have these rename to just:

```
CharacterName.wav
CharacterName_Declicked.wav
```

This is what I have so far:

```
set dirname="%cd%"

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d %%d

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e %%d_%%e

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e %%e

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f %%e_%%f
```

The issue here is that if we have a file that is called **Name_Project_Project2_Date_CharacterName.wav** it will call it **Date_CharacterName.wav** as the script isn't specifically looking for _Declicked and I can't seem to get it to work by trying to filter it.

Ideal solution would be to find which files have the extension *Declicked and only run those through the %%d*%%e and %%e_%%f lines and not the rest.

Hope this makes any sense at all!

Comment: `...in ('dir /b %dirname%\*_declicked.*') do ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('dir /B') do call :Rename "%%a"
goto :EOF

:Rename original
set "original=%~1"
set "last=%original:_=" & set "lastButOne=!last!" & set "last=%"
if "%last%" equ "Declicked.wav" (
   ren "%~1" "%lastButOne%_%last%"
) else (
   ren "%~1" "%last%"
)
exit /B
```

If you want to know how the method works, remove the `@echo off` line and carefully review the executed code. For a further explanation, see [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429).

Comment: Just a quick one - how would I make it so this ran on all subdirectories in the folder that batch is on? Thanks

Comment: Hi again everyone, after a lot of trying I still can't get this script to work for all subdirectories as well, is there something I'm missing? Been using /s but to no avail at any point even after referencing other scripts. Thanks again

Comment: If you change `dir /B` by `dir /B /S *.wav` (as suggested) and change `set "original=%~1"` by `set "original=%~NX1"` (to eliminate the _new_ path), then this should work on all subdirectories...